# How to use an absolute path declared in another workspace

Tags: typescript, jestjs, cypress

I'm having a problem with cypress.

I have a repository with 3 workspaces, backend / common / frontend.

```
package/
  backend/
    jest.config.cjs
    tsconfig.json
    utils/
  common/
    jest.config.cjs
    tsconfig.json
    utils/
      helpers/
  frontend/
    cypress.config.ts
    tsconfig.json
    utils/
```

In the workspace *common*, I have created absolute paths.

- Backend

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@package-common": "workspace:^",
}
```

**jest.config.cjs**

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '@utilsCommon/(.*)$': '@package-common/utils/$1',
  },
};
```

- Common

**jest.config.cjs**

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '@utilsCommon/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/utils/$1',
  },
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@utilsCommon/*": ["utils/*"]
    }
  },
}
```

- Frontend

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@package-common": "workspace:^",
}
```

**cypress.config.ts**

```
on(
    'file:preprocessor',
    webpack({
      webpackOptions: {
        resolve: {
          ...
          alias: {
            '@utilsCommon': resolve(__dirname, '../common/utils'),
          },
        },
```

When I run my tests via Cypress or Jest, it doesn't find my functions imported via the alias in my file in my common package.

**./common/utils/services/http.service.ts**

```
import {
  getUrlApiFhirStaging,
} from '@utilsCommon/helpers';
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etfPx.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEb40.png)

I tried to modify the cypress.config.ts file but without success.

**cypress.config.ts**

```
on(
    'file:preprocessor',
    webpack({
      webpackOptions: {
        resolve: {
          ...
          alias: {
            '@utilsCommon': resolve('@package-common/utils'),
          },
        },
```

Comment: Please add `@utilsCommon/helpers` details.

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't with your alias (at least the first one) works fine

```js
on(
    'file:preprocessor',
    webpack({
      webpackOptions: {
        resolve: {
          ...
          alias: {
            '@utilsCommon': resolve(__dirname, '../common/utils'),
          },
        },
```

The problem is with your export (or maybe import).

If I use a **named export** in `helper`, it works

```js
export const getUrlApiFhirStaging = () => 'surprise'
```

If I change to a **default export**

```js
const getUrlApiFhirStaging = () => 'surprise'
export default getUrlApiFhirStaging
```

I get the error

> (0 , utilsCommon_helpers__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_.getUrlApiFhirStaging) is not a function

Conversely, if I change the import to

```js
import getUrlApiFhirStaging from '@utilsCommon/helpers';
```

the error goes away.

Comment: Indeed, the problem doesn't have to be with absolute paths. I'll continue my investigation.
Thanks for your feedback.